# NgModule vs Component

Tags: angular

So I'm learning angular2 now and reading ngbook2 about the modules.
Modules contain components, but also can import different modules with their public components.

And the question is: What is the scope of the module component (in this meaning scope as parts of an application, not the reach of variables inside). Is module the whole application or just some part like header, containing its components?

What is the typicaly used convention?

Comment: It can be both, you will typically have an app level module that imports, declares, bootstraps, etc. everything.  But you can also have smaller modules that have their own components, etc. This smaller module is imported by the primary module.

Comment: The beginning of the Angular 2 Architecture document has an excellent overview that explains modules and components and their relationships to each other: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A common way is to see a module as a distinct feature implementation, that can consist of zero or more services, components, directives, and pipes and import modules that are used to implement that feature.

A module can define what of its content it exports to be made available for importers.

An application can consist of one or more modules with the root module importing zero or more modules where each imported module can import zero or more modules.

Modules can also be used to 
- split an app into parts that can be lazy loaded 
- reused in different applications 
- to create a naming scope for selectors.

A component is a reusable *visual* building block for the user interface that is rendered as HTML with event handlers to react on user actions and model data changes.

Comment: I am guessing that an Angular2/4/5 module is used for multi-page apps

Comment: where each page in the multi-page app is a feature

Comment: No, a module is to split an app into parts that can be lazy loaded or reused in different applications or to create a naming scope for selectors. Angular doesn't know or support multi-page apps in any way (but also doesn't prevent it)

Comment: yes I think you're right, maybe mention that in your answer

Comment: Good explanation on Module, but what is a component? How about a Module is **like** a .cs file in .NET, so it can "using" (import) other .cs (module) or being imported. A Component is just a very vague logical thing always hanging under Module. Therefore, sometimes a Component could be a method/function inside of a Module. And sometimes when a Module being referred to is the top level one, then any sub-Module can be viewed as a component. In a nutshell, Module is always at higher level than a component.

Answer (score 5):

In one whole application, there can be one main Module.
But your application can be divided into multiple modules and can be injected into the Main Module.
Let's say you have a big application library which contains movies, trailer, songs etc.
You gave the main app Module name 'MyApp'.
but further you divided your app into multiple components say.

- MovieComponent
- SongComponent (further divided into AudioComponent and VideoComponent)
- TrailerComponent

All these Component developed and tested individually and integrated to our MyAppModule.

In case anything happens in our Trailer part we can discard/test our TrailerComponent.

So It is easy to maintain a large Applications.

*I hope this will help you to understand. any suggestions most welcomed*

Comment: did you mean to say MovieModule, SongModule etc? a bit confused since you said divided into multiple modules then divided them into components instead. When would you have multiple modules vs multiple components?

Comment: The concept is not as simple as dividing and combining.